# How to get sku's of selected bundle products from order item?

Tags: orders, bundled-product, bundle

I see only product titles of products that are selected in product_options property of order item. Is there any way to get ids or skus of those products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$order->getAllItems()` use the sales item collection itself:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$order_id));
```

Where `$order_id` is the **entity_id** of the sales_order.

To use this collection, iterate over it - all items are available, even children items of bundles and configurables -- e.g. not just visible items:

```
foreach($collection as $_item){
        var_dump($_item->getSku());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, confusing answer... getAllItems() will return all the items from the sales collection even children items of bundles and configurables. It is the getAllVisibleItems() method that returns only parent items.

Comment: @BlueC 4 year old answer but thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there is a way to get the option skus from the order item - and without having to load any products. Observe!

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
    $optionIds = array_keys($options['info_buyRequest']['bundle_option']);
    $types = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::getTypes();
    $typemodel = Mage::getSingleton($types[Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE]['model']);
    $typemodel->setConfig($types[Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE]);
    $selections = $typemodel->getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $item);
    $selection_map = array();
    foreach($selections->getData() as $selection) {
        if(!isset($selection_map[$selection['option_id']])) {
            $selection_map[$selection['option_id']] = array();
        }
        $selection_map[$selection['option_id']][$selection['selection_id']] = $selection;
    }
    $chosen_skus = array();
    foreach($options['info_buyRequest']['bundle_option'] as $op => $sel) {
        $chosen_skus[] = $selection_map[$op][$sel]['sku'];
    }
    echo "Item ".Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->
        getAttributeRawValue($item->getProductId(), 'sku', $item->getStoreId()).
        " has chosen SKUs: ".implode(', ', $chosen_skus)."\n";
}
```

Comment: Have not tried it but it might work. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 2):

The items are stored in the sales_flat_order_item table as seperate rows (items), the items have the parent_item_id field set to the ID of the bundle product row.

Comment: Don't access the database directly.

Comment: It explains some things but is not a direct answer. Thanks anyway.